# Cauchy sequence of functions means Cauchy sequence of function's values?

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

In my lecture notes, the professor says:

Let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a Cauchy sequence of continuous functions $f:[t_0,t_1]\to \mathbb R^n$. For each $t\in[t_0,t_1]$, $\{f_n(t)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence of vectors in $\mathbb R^n$.

**Question** : I'd like to know why is this the case?

Note that we define $\{v_i\}_{i=0}^{\infty}$ to be a Cauchy sequence if and only if

$$
\forall\varepsilon>0\,\,\exists N\in \mathbb N\text{ such that }\forall m\ge N,\,\,\|v_m-v_N\|<\varepsilon
$$

Please take the infinity norm:

$$
\|f\|_\infty=\max_{t\in[t_0,t_1]}{\|f(t)\|_2}
$$

Comment: These functions are given to be Cauchy in what sense?

Comment: How is the norm defined? Most likely, $$\lVert f\rVert = \sup \{ \lvert f(t)\rvert : t \in [t_0,t_1]\}.$$ Then, what follows about the relation between $\lvert v_m(t) - v_n(t)\rvert$ and $\lVert v_m - v_n\rVert$?

Comment: Take the infinity norm, i.e.
$$
\|f\|_\infty=\max_{t\in[t_0,t_1]}{\|f(t)\|_2}
$$

Comment: The infinity norm requires the functions to have distance going to 0 at all points. So for any point, the functions must have distance going to 0.

Answer (score 0):

When we talk about a Cauchy sequence, we need to equip a norm on the space.

You are saying about the space $X=\{f| f:[t_0,t_1]\rightarrow R^n\}$

The important thing is what is the norm on $X$.

In this case, since the norm is not specified, your professor maybe intend to say about the Cauchy sequence pointwisely.

Just my opinion. Thank you.

Comment: I added an edit to specify that the infinity norm should be used.